# Table data in a certain format

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, pivot

I am trying to get the data which is in this format

```
Tname   FY  FPY Week
test1   87  78  1
test1   45  34  2
test1   34  89  3
test1   34  56  4
test1   56  78  5
test1   68  45  6
test2   45  89  1
test2   76  65  2
test2   45  54  3
test3   56  57.8    2
test4   34  55  4
test4   32  52.2    7
test3   78  49.4    3
test5   89  46.6    2
test5   90  43.8    1
test5   98  41  6
test5   91  38.2    7
test6   92  35.4    5
test6   93  32.6    6
```

TO DISPLAY THE RESULTS AS

```
Tname   week1       Week2       Week3       Week4       Week5       Week6       Week7   
    FY  FPY FY  FPY FY  FPY FY  FPY FY  FPY FY  FPY FY  FPY
test1   87  78  45  34  34  89  34  56  56  78  68  45  NULL    NULL
test2   45  89  76  65  45  54  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
test3   NULL    NULL    56  57.8    78  49.4    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
test4   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    34  55  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    32  52.2
test5   90  43.8    89  46.6    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    98  41  91  38.2
test6   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    92  35.4    93  32.6    NULL    NULL
```

I would like achieve this using stored procedure or gridview. Please advise

Comment: At the very least, can you understand your own post?

Comment: Try using [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to convert row data into column data.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: Will the number of weeks always be 7 or will it be dynamic?

Comment: The number of weeks will be dynamic

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specific what RDBMS you are using but your previous questions were tagged with SQL Server so this answer assumes that as your database.

There are a few ways that you can get the result.  One straightforward way, would be to use an aggregate function with a CASE expression similar to:

```
select tname,
  sum(case when week = 1 then FY end) Week1FY,
  sum(case when week = 1 then FPY end) Week1FPY,
  sum(case when week = 2 then FY end) Week2FY,
  sum(case when week = 2 then FPY end) Week2FPY,
  sum(case when week = 3 then FY end) Week3FY,
  sum(case when week = 3 then FPY end) Week3FPY,
  sum(case when week = 4 then FY end) Week4FY,
  sum(case when week = 4 then FPY end) Week4FPY,
  sum(case when week = 5 then FY end) Week5FY,
  sum(case when week = 5 then FPY end) Week5FPY,
  sum(case when week = 6 then FY end) Week6FY,
  sum(case when week = 6 then FPY end) Week6FPY,
  sum(case when week = 7 then FY end) Week7FY,
  sum(case when week = 7 then FPY end) Week7FPY
from yourtable
group by tname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1843b/7).

Since you need to PIVOT on two columns, you will first what to unpivot the data in the `FY` and `FPY` columns, then apply the PIVOT function.  Again depending on your RDBMS, there are several ways to unpivot data I am showing how to do it using CROSS APPLY and UNION ALL:

```
select tname, 
  col = 'week_'+cast(week as varchar(2))+'_'+col, 
  value
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  select 'FY', FY union all
  select 'FPY', FPY 
) c (col, value)
```

The unpivot process converts your data from the multiple columns into multiple rows:

```
| TNAME |        COL | VALUE |
|-------|------------|-------|
| test1 |  week_1_FY |    87 |
| test1 | week_1_FPY |    78 |
| test1 |  week_2_FY |    45 |
| test1 | week_2_FPY |    34 |
| test1 |  week_3_FY |    34 |
```

Then you can apply the PIVOT function:

```
select tname,
  week_1_FY, week_1_FPY, week_2_FY, week_2_FPY,
  week_3_FY, week_3_FPY, week_4_FY, week_4_FPY,
  week_5_FY, week_5_FPY, week_6_FY, week_6_FPY,
  week_7_FY, week_7_FPY
from
(
  select tname, 
    col = 'week_'+cast(week as varchar(2))+'_'+col, 
    value
  from yourtable
  cross apply
  (
    select 'FY', FY union all
    select 'FPY', FPY 
  ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for col in (week_1_FY, week_1_FPY, week_2_FY, week_2_FPY,
              week_3_FY, week_3_FPY, week_4_FY, week_4_FPY,
              week_5_FY, week_5_FPY, week_6_FY, week_6_FPY,
              week_7_FY, week_7_FPY)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1843b/10).

Finally if the number of week will be unknown, then you can use dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @weekstart int = 1,
  @weekend int = 4

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('week_'+cast(week as varchar(2))+'_'+col) 
                    from yourtable
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'FY', 1 union all
                      select 'FPY', 2
                    ) c (col, so)
                    where week >= @weekstart
                        and week <= @weekend
                    group by col, so, week
                    order by week, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT tname, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select tname, 
                col = ''week_''+cast(week as varchar(2))+''_''+col, 
                value
              from yourtable
              cross apply
              (
                select ''FY'', FY union all
                select ''FPY'', FPY 
              ) c (col, value)
              where week >= '+cast(@weekstart as varchar(2))+'
                and week <= '+cast(@weekend as varchar(2))+'
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1843b/19). All versions give a result of:

```
| TNAME | WEEK_1_FY | WEEK_1_FPY | WEEK_2_FY | WEEK_2_FPY | WEEK_3_FY | WEEK_3_FPY | WEEK_4_FY | WEEK_4_FPY | WEEK_5_FY | WEEK_5_FPY | WEEK_6_FY | WEEK_6_FPY | WEEK_7_FY | WEEK_7_FPY |
|-------|-----------|------------|-----------|------------|-----------|------------|-----------|------------|-----------|------------|-----------|------------|-----------|------------|
| test1 |        87 |         78 |        45 |         34 |        34 |         89 |        34 |         56 |        56 |         78 |        68 |         45 |    (null) |     (null) |
| test2 |        45 |         89 |        76 |         65 |        45 |         54 |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |
| test3 |    (null) |     (null) |        56 |         58 |        78 |         49 |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |
| test4 |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |        34 |         55 |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |        32 |         52 |
| test5 |        90 |         44 |        89 |         47 |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |        98 |         41 |        91 |         38 |
| test6 |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |        92 |         35 |        93 |         33 |    (null) |     (null) |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped me a lot. I get to this data format( as asked in the question) using  a very complicated stored procedure and many joins with many tables. So my question is, is it possible to have the colnames as dynamic. Sometimes it might be week number 10-15 and some other times 10-20 or 15-17 etc. It could be any week numbers. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: @user1984533 yes, you can use dynamic sql if the weeks are unknown, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TName, [1] as Week1FY, [2] as Week2FY, [3] as Week3FY, 
        [4] as Week4FY, [5] as Week5FY, [6] as Week6FY, [7] as Week7FY
    FROM( SELECT t.TName, t.FY, t.Week FROM Table t
    PIVOT
        ( MAX(FY) FOR Week in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
    )) as P
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT TName, [1] as Week1FPY, [2] as Week2FPY, [3] as Week3FPY,
        [4] as Week4FPY, [5] as Week5FPY, [6] as Week6FPY, [7] as Week7FPY
    FROM( SELECT t.TName, t.FPY, t.Week FROM Table t
    PIVOT
        ( MAX(FPY) FOR Week in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
    )) as Q ON P.TName = Q.TName
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Really appreciate the time that you took to respond.